# Shapefile for post codes in Portugal?

Tags: shapefile, data, postal-code, portugal

I'm looking for shapefiles of the Portugal post codes 4 digits.

Any open source or fee source that will have this info?

Comment: I think this question would be more on-topic at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Portugal 4-Digit Postcode Areas, 2005 (download as shapefile) http://gis.lib.virginia.edu/catalog/princeton-0v8381988

Comment: unable to download the Shapefile, the server didn't find it .. error 404

Answer (score 3):

I agree you are best asking this on the Open Data stack exchange. But there is this great search tool called Google, type *anything* like "free portugal postcode data" and first thing it throws up is this:

https://www.aggdata.com/free/portugal-postal-codes

Note it is out of date as it appears to be fixed at 2012, but it links through to the original source of the data.

Comment: It's not exactly what I'm looking for. yes the source doesn't have to be accurate as much as that but I am looking for a Shapefile already created not a csv file !!  thank you for your answer